# Python create makefile of dependencies

Tags: python, makefile

I have a Makefile based project and some python scripts which create plot files, e.g. (in my Makefile)

```
plot.pdf: my_script.py
    python my_script.py -o $@
```

Usually these scripts have dependencies on data e.g. `my_data.txt`, so I added this into my Makefile

```
plot.pdf: my_script.py my_data.txt
    python my_script.py -o $@
```

This is very cumbersome, as I need to keep the Makefile and python script in sync. So I switched to exporting Make rules from the python script:

```
plot.pdf: my_script.py
    python my_script.py -o $@ --make-mode
```

`--make-mode` will write a Makefile which states the dependency of `plot.pdf` on  `my_data.txt`. My Makefile is set up to source all these auto generated Makefiles.

To support incremental builds when I change my python script I stated the dependency of `plot.pdf` on `my_script.py`. But `my_script.py` also depends on other python scripts written by me. If I change these scripts e.g. `utils.py`, my file `plot.pdf` will not be updated. **Is there a way to get the file paths of the imported python scripts from within python, so I can add them to my auto generated Makefile?** Or can you recommend an alternative approach?

Comment: you may also be interested in the https://pydoit.org tool. It is a make-like system that is programmable through python.

Comment: pydoit looks interesting indeed, I will consider it for my next project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer which made me happy:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(
     [modu.__file__ for modu in sys.modules.values() 
          if '__file__' in dir(modu) 
          and modu.__file__ is not None]
))
```

which contains both the system python scripts **as well as** my user scripts.

Comment: If that answers your question, kindly mark it as such.

Comment: I will in 32 minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each imported python script becomes available as a module. This module exposes the `__file__` attribute that contains the filename of the script:

```
import my_other_script
print(my_other_script.__file__)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves already half of what I need. Is there a way to do this for all imported **user** scripts? I mean without listing them explicitly.

Comment: I don't understand. When you import a user script, you must list it explicitly with an `import` statement, right?

Comment: Check out modulefinder https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html

Comment: I did, but for me it only found includes from other packages. The documentation wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done, example if I wanted to know the location of the os module.

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath(os.__file__)
print (path)

path = os.path.dirname(os.__file__)
print (path)
```

Results

```
PS D:\Coding\pytest> python run.py
C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\os.py
C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib
PS D:\Coding\pytest>
```